# Make Event FormClose

Tags: delphi

I'm doing a form manually, I have what I need but want to control the FormClose event, but can not find information on how to do it, I just want to create the event and FormClose code from the display.

What I have is:

```
function make_form():bool;
    var
      frm: TForm;
    begin
      frm := TForm.Create(nil);
      frm.Caption := 'Title';
      frm.Width := 500;
      frm.Height := 300;
    end;
```

This code is a function in a unit

How can I do this ?

Comment: You leak the form. You don't set the return value. The form cannot be shown. Please don't show fake code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your functions is useless

Use try..finally when you creating an object.

Start with something like this

```
type
  // Dummy class:
  TFrmHandlers = class
    // Close handlers:
    class procedure FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
  end;

implementation

.....

class procedure TFrmHandlers.FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
begin
  ShowMessage('The form will closed now');
end;

procedure make_form();
var
  frm: TForm;
begin
  frm := TForm.Create(nil);
  try
    frm.Caption := 'Title';
    frm.Width := 500;
    frm.Height := 300;
    frm.OnClose := TFrmHandlers.FormClose;
    frm.ShowModal;
  finally
    frm.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: May I ask why did you use `class procedure` instead of regular one? You do realize that by doing so are exposing potential bug of calling that method without any existing TFrmHandlers instance. And if that method is trying to access any data that would belong to TFrmHandlers instance it would result in AV.

Comment: @SilverWarior `access any data that would belong to TFrmHandlers instance it would result in AV.` that is the inquirer responsibility, I assumed the inquirer dos not have a appropriate class to put the close event on it. but even so he shouldn't have to create an instance of that dummy class but he can assign the handler to it.

Comment: Ahh! Now I see why you used class procedure. You did it because the procedure is part od that dummy class. This is understandable. But you should warn the OP that in such case it should not be using `Self` as it will not be referencing form class instance but instead the dummy class instance. And this could lead to lots of confusion on OP part.

Comment: @Silver You've got that wrong. In a class method `Self` refers to the class and not an instance. After all, how could it refer to an instance in a class method. No instances need to be created at all here.

Answer (score 0):

You code is not real.

To treat Close event in dynamically created form, you have to assign event handler to event property OnClose:

```
frm.OnClose := CloseProc;
```

`CloseProc` should be a method of some object (for example, of main form) with needed prototype

```
 TFormMain = class(TForm)
 ...
    procedure CloseProc(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
...
implementation
    procedure TformMain.CloseProc(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
     begin
        //use Sender if needed
     end;
```

Comment: how create the method object ?

Comment: Use the same approach as IDE makes event handlers. See example

Comment: thanks , when update the source with your help , the source has this new error Undeclared identifier: 'CloseProc'

Comment: Because `CloseProc` belongs to some object or class (as RepeatUntil shown) and you have to specify namespace (if you code is not inside that class methods)